# Is it possible to compact a VirtualBox .vdi image while the guest is running?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, disk-space

I've been searching for that question on Google, on this site and in VirtualBox forums and I couldn't find anything related to it. Since nowadays partitions can be resized, encrypted, cloned, ... while the system is running (even if it's the partition that stores the running operating system), is it possible to do `vboxmanage --compact` on the disk of a running guest?

If not, can it be done to the .vdi of a Saved VM? (i.e. after closing it using "Save the machine state")

(It's a Windows 10 guest inside a Debian 11 host)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Virtualbox' manual on the topic](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#vboxmanage-modifymedium) is rather scarce about the constraints of some actions, I tried it to have some closure:

My testsetup comprises Virtualbox 7.0.8, Debian 11 on the host and guest, with dynamically allocated vdi-diskimages. I could successfully run

```
vboxmanage modifymedium path/to/harddrive.vdi --compact
```

as well as a Snapshot

```
vboxmanage modifymedium path/to/Snapshots/{uuid}.vdi --compact
```

when the machine was closed using `Save the machine state`
or `Shutdown via ACPI-Event`.

I **could not** compact neither the base-image nor the snapshot when the VM was running.
The following error message was given:

```
VBoxManage: error: Failed to lock media when compacting 'path/to/harddrive.vdi'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "Compact(pProgress.asOutParam())" at line 912 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
VBoxManage: error: Failed to compact medium!
```

Comment: Did it output some error?

Comment: Yes, it did give an error. I added it to my answer via an edit.